# Left outer join difference in various databases

Tags: sql, join

I help in understanding the difference in the way various databases interpret left outer join.

In a scenario where there is 1:1 relationship between the left and right table, I would imagine the count of join operation will be exactly equal to the count in the left table.

I have observed this to be true for MS SQL but Oracle (PL/SQL) seems to be having a different interpretation of this. The count of a left outer join in Oracle is the sum of all entries in the left table + the matching entries in the right.

Kindly confirm if I am correct in my understanding and what is the best methodif we have to reconcile data between Oracle and MS SQL.

The code is -

```
select distinct NVL(L11, NVL(L10, NVL(L9, NVL(L8, NVL(L7, NVL(L6, NVL(L5, NVL(L4, NVL(L3, NVL(L2, NVL(L1,       NVL(L0,'ERR')))))))))))) ENDITEM, case when l1 = 'Raw Wafer' then l0
 when l2 = 'ABC' then l1
 when l3 = 'ABC' then l2
 when l4 = 'ABC' then l3
 when l5 = 'ABC' then l4
 when l6 = 'ABC' then l5
 when l7 = 'ABC' then l6
 when l8 = 'ABC' then l7
 when l9 = 'ABC' then l8
 when l10 = 'ABC' then l9
 when l11 = 'ABC' then l10 end item, g1.item bl1, g2.item bl2, g3.item bl3, g4.item bl4, g5.item bl5, g6.item     bl6, g7.item bl7, g8.item bl8, g9.item bl9, g10.item bl10, g11.item bl11, 
decode(g1.item, null, 0, 1) + decode(g2.item, null, 0, 1)  + decode(g3.item, null, 0, 1) + decode(g4.item,      null, 0, 1) + decode(g5.item, null, 0, 1) + decode(g6.item, null, 0, 1) + decode(g7.item, null, 0, 1) +    decode(g8.item, null, 0, 1) + decode(g9.item, null, 0, 1) + decode(g10.item, null, 0, 1) + decode(g11.item, null, 0, 1) cnt,
gg.* from  TABL1 gg
left outer join TABL2 g1 on g1.item = gg.l1
left outer join TABL2 g2 on g2.item = gg.l2
left outer join TABL2 g3 on g3.item = gg.l3          
left outer join TABL2 g4 on g4.item = gg.l4          
left outer join TABL2 g5 on g5.item = gg.l5          
left outer join TABL2 g6 on g6.item = gg.l6
left outer join TABL2 g7 on g7.item = gg.l7
left outer join TABL2 g8 on g8.item = gg.l8
left outer join TABL2 g9 on g9.item = gg.l9
left outer join TABL2 g10 on g10.item = gg.l10
left outer join TABL2 g11 on g11.item = gg.l11
```

when I do a count on this MS SQL suggests only the count from TABL1 while Oracle seems to be proposing more.

Thanks.

Comment: Oracle should behave the same way - I suspect your join condition or syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Left outer join is defined in a standard way for all databases.  Please post the Oracle code; it is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: Agreed with above comments this is a coding issue.

Comment: If there was a difference between LEFT JOIN implementations in Oracle and MSSQL there would be a lot of questions and answers around this. Please show us your code.

Comment: @DStanley I have posted the code, please advise. this is the oracle code. Thanks.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have posted the code, pl advise. this is the oracle code.

Comment: @Namphibian  i have posted the code, pl advise. this is the oracle code

Comment: Rather than chaining bazillion NVLs, use COALESCE(L11, L10, ..., L0, 'ERR') (->[doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617))

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps a bit too long for a comment.

First, if you are comparing queries in different databases, why are you showing code that works in only one of them?  This query can be written in a standard way across databases, quite easily, using `case` and `coalesce()`.

Without seeing the results, I can think of two differences that might arise.  The first is that you are running different queries on different data in the different databases.  Let's ignore that, because there is another possibility.

Oracle treats NULL string values and empty string values as the same.  This has all sorts of repercussions, particularly when using `NVL()` (or doing an aggregation and getting one row instead of two).  My guess is that this unstandard "feature" of Oracle is causing different results.

You can phrase the query differently to get the same result in all databases, by using case.  Replace the `nvl(val1, val2)` with:

```
(case when val1 is null or val1 = '' then val2 else val1 end)
```